# Spring cloud data flow Browser Console Errors

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I recently upgraded to use local data flow server to 1.7.0 RELEASE.
Upon creating the stream, when using the deploy button in the browser - hangs forever saying "loading". I do see some errors on the console developer tools as well.. some inside main.js etc.
The chrome browser version that I am using:

```
Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Is any one else seeing. I also confirmed clearing browsing cache both in IE and Chrome the problem persists. I see errors on F12 dev tools, upon clicking on the Runtime tab

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json
enter code here
```

Thanks for your help.

About and Docs info as requested

```
"versionInfo": {
    "implementation": {
      "name": "spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local",
      "version": "1.7.3.RELEASE"
    },
    "core": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Data Flow Core",
      "version": "1.7.3.RELEASE"
    },
    "dashboard": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Dataflow UI",
      "version": "1.7.2.RELEASE"
    },
    "shell": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Data Flow Shell",
      "version": "1.7.3.RELEASE",
      "url": "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-shell/1.7.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar"
    }
  },
  "featureInfo": {
    "analyticsEnabled": true,
    "streamsEnabled": true,
    "tasksEnabled": true,
    "skipperEnabled": false,
    "schedulerEnabled": false
  },
  "securityInfo": {
    "isAuthenticationEnabled": false,
    "isAuthorizationEnabled": false,
    "isFormLogin": false,
    "isAuthenticated": false,
    "username": null,
    "roles": []
  },
  "runtimeEnvironment": {
    "appDeployer": {
      "platformSpecificInfo": {},
      "deployerImplementationVersion": "1.3.10.RELEASE",
      "deployerName": "LocalAppDeployer",
      "deployerSpiVersion": "1.3.4.RELEASE",
      "javaVersion": "1.8.0_192",
      "platformApiVersion": "Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformClientVersion": "3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformHostVersion": "3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformType": "Local",
      "springBootVersion": "1.5.16.RELEASE",
      "springVersion": "4.3.19.RELEASE"
    },
    "taskLauncher": {
      "platformSpecificInfo": {},
      "deployerImplementationVersion": "1.3.10.RELEASE",
      "deployerName": "LocalTaskLauncher",
      "deployerSpiVersion": "1.3.4.RELEASE",
      "javaVersion": "1.8.0_192",
      "platformApiVersion": "Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformClientVersion": "3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformHostVersion": "3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64",
      "platformType": "Local",
      "springBootVersion": "1.5.16.RELEASE",
      "springVersion": "4.3.19.RELEASE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you confirm what happens when you clear-cache and reload the browser?  (mac: cmd+ shift + r)

Comment: If it continues, it would be useful if you could edit the post to include the browser-console errors, so we can review.

Comment: I changed the post title as suggested, and also verified that it occurs with clear browsing history.

Comment: Hi! Can you share the about details (copy/past available in http://localhost:4200/#/about)?

Comment: http://172.24.172.227:9393/dashboard/#/about

Comment: Data Flow Server Implementation

Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local
Version: 1.7.3.RELEASE

Comment: Could you: Navigate to the `About & Docs` page, expand the `Data Flow Server Implementation` (click arrow), click on `Copy Details to Clipboard`. Then, you can create a gist to share it.

Comment: Added in the main section per request

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any javascript errors on other pages (apps, tasks, about, runtime ...) on Chrome/IE?

Comment: Can yo also have a look on the Network tab in Chrome (any errors)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185515/discussion-between-damien-vitrac-and-deepali-bhandari).